# How to clear value from magic suggest

Tags: javascript, jquery, magicsuggest

How to clear input value from magic suggest. While selecting value from select box, Based on the select box selection **Magic suggest** value need to clear or **magic suggest** need to be initialise again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
removeFromSelection(object / array[object], isSilent:boolean)
```

Remove one or multiples json items from the current selection. Set isSilent to true to prevent event trigger.